# How to reindex the rows in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a modifed df but the rows index is changed so how to let it start from 0 and so on

Example :

2   Mc-system   commercial

3   Mf-System   educational

20  Mk-system   fundemntal

I want it to be like this :

0  Mc-system   commercial

1  Mf-System   educational

2  Mk-system   fundemntal

So that the row index is organized

Comment: Your question isn't clear, are you reading an excel file or do you want to reset the index of your dataframe

Comment: Yes i want to reset the index of the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use
[dataframe.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```py
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```